# unpack binary file in PHP

Tags: php, binary, unpack

I'm trying to parse a Binary File in PHP which is an attachment of a Document in a NoSQL DB. However, in my tests, if the size of a file is of 1MB, the unpacking lasts for around 12-15 seconds. The file contains information about speed from a sensor.

The binary file converted to hexadecimal is structured as follow:

```
BB22 1100 0015 XXXX ...
BB22 1300 0400 20FB 5900 25FB 5910 ... 20FB 5910
BB22 1100 0015 ...
BB22 1300 0400 20FB 5700 25FB 5810 ... 20FB 5912
BB22 1300 0400 20FB 5700 25FB 5810 ... 20FB 5912
...
```

The marker `BB22 1100` contains the sensor specification, while `0015` refers to the size of that information.

The marker `BB22 1300` contains other data plus the actual speed from the sensor. The next two bytes `0400` represent the length of that chunk, which is of 1024 bytes.

I'm only interested in the speed which are the values e.g. `5900 5910 5910 5700 5810 ...`

My approach is as follow:

```
$file = fopen($url, 'r', false, authenticationContext($url));
$result = stream_get_contents($file, -1);
fclose($file);

$hex_result = bin2hex($result);

$markerData = 'bb2213';
$sensorDataUnpack= "sspeed"; // signed int16 

while(($pos = strpos($hex_result, $markerData, $pos)) !== FALSE){
    $pos=$pos+4;
    for ($j=4; $j<1028; $j=$j+4) { 
       $d =  unpack($sensorDataUnpack, substr($result, $pos/2+$j+2));       
       $sensorData[] = $d; 
    }
}
```

I converted the results from binary to hexadecimal because it wasn't working for me to get the positions properly. Anyway, I believe this code can be very much improved, any ideas?.

Comment: You should really consider of creating a C or C++ program that does that job and collects the `sensorData`. Then you just run that program with the appropriate arguments from inside your PHP script and collect the results. It requires a bit more work, but you'll have your results much faster. Of course that requires PHP to have shell functions not blocked by your server provider in order to run the external program. You can also try and switch to PHP 7.x. It's much faster then older PHP versions.

Comment: @ChristosLytras, yes probably a good approach could be as you suggest.
@CrouchingKitten, Sorry. I'm just following the documentation of the function pack `s - signed short (always 16 bit, machine byte order)`. What do you mean with   `p`?

Comment: Ah I see now, sorry I missed the naming part in the unpack format code. One question: from the data you always want every second small int value only? Why are these skipped? "20FB" "25FB"

Comment: They are being skipped because they are accelerometer data that I actually don't need (at least for now). And their data structure is `"cx/cy/"`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fast, but without test data I wasn't able to test it.

The key points are these:

- Open the URL as binary, and use the fread() to help in positioning and in slicing up the data to parts.
- Use the unpack both for parsing the headers and the bodies of the entries as well.
- Use the asterisk * repeater to quickly parse the big bodies for signed shorts.
- Use array_values() to convert the associative array to a simple array with numeric keys (like: 0, 1, 2, ...).

Update: I solved the endianness and bitness problem around the marker comparison by using the "H4" pack format to get a hexa string in big endian order.

```
    $sensorData = array();
    $file = fopen($url, 'rb', false, authenticationContext($url));

    while (($header = fread($file, 6)) !== false) {
        $fields = unpack("H4marker/ssize", $header);

        $body = fread($file, $fields["size"] * 2);

        if ($body === false) {
            throw new Exception("import: data stream unexpectedly ended.");
        }

        if ($fields["marker"] == "BB221300") {
            $data = array_values(unpack("s*", $body));

            // Store only every second value.
            for ($i = 1; $i < count($data); $i+=2) {
                $sensorData[] = $data[$i];
            }
        }
    }

    fclose($file);
```